# App Crashing Swift Xcode 6.1 With Certain Method

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6.1

My app is crashing on this method:

```
func loadData() {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"AllTweets")
    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)-> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            for object:AnyObject in objects {
                self.timelineData.addObject(object as PFObject)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The error that it throws is:
ECX_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

I am calling this method in my viewDidAppear method.

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and step through the code to find the exact line of the crash.

Comment: @zisoft I just did that and it shows this is the line of the crash:                 self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your code is weird. You create `let array: NSArray` and cast it to `NSMutableArray` in the next line.

Comment: @zisoft that is because self.timelineData is an NSMutable array itself, and I am setting array to timelineData.

Comment: @user3679109: I suggest you to answer the question yourself and mark it as the solution, so everybody knows what you did in order to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects will return a NSArray, no matter the type of the original array is Mutable or not. (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSEnumerator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSEnumerator/allObjects)

In swift, if you need a mutable array, then use

```
var mutableArray = array.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
```

var is for mutable and let is the opposite.